# Android - A card item in gridview is repeated twice

Tags: java, android, gridview

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
  private Activity context;
  private int[] icon;
  private String[] title;

  public ListAdapter(Activity context, int[] icon, String[] title)
  {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, title);
    this.context = context;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent)
  { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
    try
    {
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
        imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(icon[position]);
    }
     catch (Exception e)
     { 
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
    finally
    {
       return rowView;
    }
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**
In this card Events is replaced with Services. When I re-shuffle the positions the changes are reflected in the app but when I run the app again the Gallery is replaced by Services.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   String[] title = {
        "Services" ,
        "Solutions",
        "Customers",
        "Events",
        "Gallery",
        "Contact Us"
    };

int[] icon = {
        R.drawable.services_icon,
        R.drawable.solution_icon,
        R.drawable.customer_icon,
        R.drawable.event_icon,
        R.drawable.gallery_icon,
        R.drawable.contact_us_icon
};

    HomeGrid adapter = new HomeGrid(MainActivity.this, title, icon, back);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            switch (title[position]) {
                case "Services":
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Listing.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                    break;
                case "Solutions":
                    //Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Listing.class);
                    //startActivity(i2);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + title[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Customers":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + title[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Gallery":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + title[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Events":
                    Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Form.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    break;
                case "Contact Us":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + title[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;   
         }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is a `HomeGrid`?

Comment: `inflater.inflate(..., true)` -> `inflater.inflate(..., false)` you don't want to attach the view to the parent just yet. The grid takes care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
 public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private Activity context;
    private int[] icon;
    private String[] title;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ListAdapter(Activity context, int[] icon, String[] title)
    {
      super(context, R.layout.list_item, title);
      this.context = context;
      this.icon = icon;
      this.title = title;
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }
 public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent)
 { 
   view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
   try
   {
     TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
     ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
     txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
     imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(icon[position]);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 finally
 {
    return view;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhavi

Comment: can you explain what you changed, why you think the problem was, and how you think your solution solves the problem?

Comment: even i could not understand the logic but that solved my issue.Explanation will help to resolve such issues in future.